# Can I model the general political landscape with mathematica?

Tags: modeling, webservices

I want to develop a website which would model a province of 2 million people from a political point of view. Is mathematica a good fit for such a project?

My background is that I'm an experienced programmer though my math isn't that hot and I have no experience of mathematica. I am looking to create a website where people would be able to tweak factors such a welfare / company tax, etc and play out different political scenarios.

I'm very aware that this is a large undertaking and this is why I'm evaluating mathematica, especially with regards to cellular automata.

Is mathematica a good fit for such a project, and if it is then am  I going to have to pay an ongoing fee to use the Wolfram API?

Thanks

Comment: *Mathematica* is not really suitable for making a website. You can do it in various ways, but I wouldn't choose this path myself. For back-end processing, maybe, in which case you will need a WebMathematica licence. The Wolfram|Alpha API charges depend on what you are using W|A for, and maybe for a website it will require a special contract with WRI to use their service in such a way. Can you be more specific about your needs in terms of the analysis and processing of the data than just "political modelling"? WRI do offer trials if that will help. This forum is totally unoffical, by the way.

Comment: If you don't know where to start thinking about this I would suggest browsing the site until you see something similar or related to part of what you envision doing. To be honest, for sales advice, I would recommend you approach WRI directly.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: You might want to post in [THIS GROUP](http://community.wolfram.com/content?curTag=wolfram%20science) If you do please give more details about the project.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses esp. Oleksandr.

I was intending to only use mathematica to model the backend of the Web site bit the renderer.

As I suspected I probably would need an ongoing license for Web mathematica which I believe will be prohibitive. Looks like I need a rethink!

I wanted to create cells of people with a number of quite simple drivers such as wages religion quality of life etc, which in turn influence other drivers such as party association. Then the inputs to it all are things like taxes that influence everyone.

Comment: @wil You can start with this, I found it in Wolfram Blog. http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/09/24/analyzing-us-2008-elections-with-mathematica/

Comment: Thanks Bob, that looks very interesting!